# How do I keep a conversation going with a potential future employer?

Tags: new-job, job-change, employer

I was recently contacted by my dream company saying that a job I applied to over six months ago has moved forward in the application process.

Of course, that was quite a while back and I have since found work. I am interested in keeping a conversation open with my dream company, however I feel as though I still have a lot to learn from my current job as I haven't been there for long (about six months). What is the best way to tell my dream company that I'm interested, just not right now?

Comment: Just to mention that if your dream company is Google, they will usually contact you every 6 months and ask if you would be interested in making another round of interviews. I suspect a lot of other famous companies do the same.

Comment: It's not Google, but it's a company about as large as them. So is that pretty common practice for large companies to do? So will I be able to reopen things up in ~6 months?

Comment: Well I can't speak for them. I'm just stating that when things go well enough during an interview, it's not uncommon for big companies to regularly ask for news. No guarantees though.

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear in my question. I haven't had an interview with them yet. They just contacted me saying that my application had moved on from the recruiters/top level to a specific team for consideration. Is it still pretty common for large companies to ask for how things are?

Comment: @BDD Yes, it's common.  Amazon, Microsoft, Google, several others have contacted me at various times initially via LinkedIn.

Comment: What things do you feel you have a lot to learn? Would you be able to learn the same things at DreamCo? Is your current job a prerequisite of sorts for your dream job? Maybe you don't need to tell them anything and see where the process goes. There's no choice to be made if there's no offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to tell my dream company that I'm interested, just not right now?

Be honest with them. Say you are interested in working from them but are not interested in a new role at this time. Many large tech companies (e.g. Amazon, Google, Microsoft) have annual intakes and will just add you to the list for next year.

Alternatively, if you are talking to a hiring manager instead of HR, keep that connection open. Have the occasional coffee with him/her, chat with him/her at user groups or conferences, wish him/her happy birthday on social networks and so on.

In the meantime, make sure you keep up with the technologies and trends your future employer will want. Keep your skills current and demonstrable. Make sure you are familiar with new products and their intended use. Focus on the business side, too, not just the technical. For example, what companies have they recently acquired? Why?

Lastly, remember that hiring at large tech companies is usually done on a schedule that benefits the tech company, not you. You may need to leave your existing work in the middle of an important project. I am not saying never take on a new project or important work. I am saying you may not be able to keep everyone happy.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not assume that in future/your dream company you will not be able to learn which you want. Mostly there will be chance to learn something new about your current job profile when you go to new company. And if company is large then its obvious that you will learn a lot.

Second thing is as per your mentioned comment they have just contacted you  and considered so to deny them at this stage is not good , Let them process and see how they move forward. If you get a chance for interview then you should face it. You will learn a lot in interview also like how large companies take interview , which type of things they ask and a lot more.

Last thing is most of large companies have rule like if you fail in interview then you can re-apply only after 6 months ,so if you pass interview then will be best , if fail then you will not jobless , you have your current job in hand and at there you can learn what you want in next 6 months. And finally after 6 months you can again apply to your dream company with double confidence.